# Does polyglossia load fontspec?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia

I am trying to use polyglossia with fontspec in LuaLatex (up to date MiKTex+TexStudio) exactly as suggested in  ["Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2ε" by Tobias Oetiker](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/) (p. 35)

```
    \usepackage{polyglossia}                   
\setdefaultlanguage[ variant=uk]{english}
\setotherlanguage[babelshorthands]{german}
    \usepackage[Ligatures=TeX]{fontspec}
```

However, this produces option clash

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.30 

The package fontspec has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [Ligatures=TeX]
Adding the global options:
  ,Ligatures=TeX
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Is it possible that polyglossia loaded fontspec, and that produced the clash?

Comment: Yes, it does. (`\RequirePackage{fontspec}[2010/06/08]`)

Comment: Load `fontspec` before `polyglossia`.  (Hint: There is no `Ligatures=TeX` option. Read the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) for allowed options.)

Comment: The `Ligatures=TeX` option is not a valid one for `fontspec` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load `fontspec` before `polyglossia`.  There is no `Liagtures=TeX` option but it's a font feature which you can enable using `\addfontfeatures`.  Also `Ligatures=TeX` is enabled by default in recent versions of `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % is enabled by default
\usepackage{polyglossia}                   
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\setotherlanguage[babelshorthands]{german}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\addfontfeatures` should be `\defaultfontfeatures`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm not so sure whether `\defaultfontfeatures` is applied to already loaded fonts (which `\fontspec` does) but I know that `\addfontfeatures` is applied on the spot.

Comment: I took the code from the supposedly very popular above mentioned book. May be I should send the author a link to this thread

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know which options `polyglossia` passes to fontspec, use:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{...the options ...}{fontspec}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                   
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\setotherlanguage[babelshorthands]{german}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

However, the latest `fontspec` has no valid optional arguments for specific font features..

Comment: that's true. I meant optional arguments for setting font options like ligatures, small caps, a.s.o. I'll edit my answer.